# Using fprintf to print on several lines in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, int, printf

Question:
Write a procedure called Print7 to print all integer numbers within the range 0:100 that are divisible by 7. Ten numbers are to be printed on one output line. Hence write a  program that invokes that procedure.

This is what I did

```
 file = fopen('print7.dat','r');

 x = 1:100

 for x=[1:100]
   if mod(x,7) == 0;
    print7 = [x]
 end
end
 fprintf('print7 %d\n', print7)
```

Now it's output becomes the number 98 - which I understand to be the largest number under 100 divisible by 7. But I want a 10xn matrix-like result.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing stores your result in a variable and overwrites the variable in each iteration. You could print it directly instead like this:

```
c=0;
 for x=[1:100]
   if mod(x,7) == 0
      fprintf('%3d',x)
      c=c+1;
      if mod(c,10) ==0
        fprintf('\n')
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: I suppose you might have trouble understand why the mod(c,10) since rest of it is pretty trivial. So with fprintf('%3d',x) we print result on the same line as it is calculates but since after every 10 results we need to write to a new line we need to write a newline character ie "\n". So I maintain a counter c which counts how many results have been calculated so far and after the 10th results we add a new line. The mod(c,10) checks for when we hit 10 with out count.

Answer (score 0):

```
fileID = fopen('print7.dat','r');

for x = 1:100
if(mod(x,7) == 0)
   fprintf(fileID,'%d',x);
end %end of if
end %end of for

fclose(fileID);
```